# If wifi admin can see what I'm doing on apps

Tags: wireless-networking

So can the wifi admin see what pictures or what I search in apps like Instagram, Twitter, Vine. Here's an example- I search fight videos on Instagram and I end up watching an Instagram video, can my wifi admin see that?

Comment: If they keep logs, they'll see every URL each client connects to.

Comment: @zacharee1 what does that mean please elaborate; go into detail

Comment: @Zacharee1 not correct - a router does not have stuff to log (but I'll expand my answer below)

Comment: @davidgo I've seen plenty of routers with logging capabilities, but if there's a "WiFi admin," I believe there is something actually set up to log client activity.

Comment: @Zacharee1 - They can only log stuff which is proxied  through them (ie using some kind of proxy server like privoxy), or raw packets which can be further analysed.   They can log connects and disconnects as well.    They can't typically log requests like you would get from, for example, an apache log - showing what URLS were requested.

Comment: @davidgo but I used a Netgear router that showed a log listing all URLs visited and which clients visited those URLs.

Comment: @Zacharee1 What model netgear were you using, and how could it have tracked HTTPS urls ?

Comment: Note that all routers are not created equal. its trivial to build a PC into a wifi router, and run arbitrary software like wireshark, Fiddler, sslstrip, etc. Such a router is not even limited in what they can inject into the connection, except perhaps VPN traffic. Most commercial routers don't have these capabilities however.

Comment: @davidgo I honestly don't remember. It's a friend's router. I had to secure the WiFi because someone had been using it to pirate music.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is "It depends".

If you are going to unencrypted sites, it is possible for anyone in the middle - including whoever it is that controls your WIFI connection - to see the traffic going in both directions.  They can see pretty much anything set "unencrypted"

In the "normal case" of going to secure (https) sites, the WIFI administrator would not be able to see exactly what you are doing.  They would be able to get a sense of it from hints - including DNS queries - which would give an indication of which services you were using - but they would not be able to see the actual content (ie what images or videos you were looking at).  They could get some vague idea what you were doing by looking at the volume of information being transferred, and the timing of data packets.

In the "special case", if the WIFI provider has put a root cert on your computer or is otherwise forcing you to use a proxy they can see exactly what you are doing - as if it was unencrypted.  In most cases they can't practically do this - unless its a corporate environment - as they need access to the software running on your computer.